# Confusion over using Ninject using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

after lots of efforts in DI i could finally figure out the basics,but as long as i know up to now,instantiating or using NEW key word in the controller means we are still not satisfying the DI,i have created a small project to point out my problem:

```
public  interface IOperations
{
    int mul(int a, int b);
}
```

The implementation of my Interface:

```
 public class Operations:IOperations
{

  public  int mul(int a,int b){


        return a * b;

}
 }
```

In my controller i create my constructor :

```
private IOperations _ioperations;

    public HomeController(IOperations _ioperations)
    {


        this._ioperations = _ioperations;
    }
```

Handler class:

```
  public readonly IOperations _ioperation;

    public Handeler(IOperations _ioperation)
    {


        this._ioperation = _ioperation;

    }
```

Binding class:

```
 public class Binding:NinjectModule
{

    public override void Load()
    {


        Bind<IOperations>().To<Operations>();


        }
    }
}
```

and at the end my controller:

```
 var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        var _operation = kernel.Get<IOperations>();


        var handler = new Handeler(_operation);
        var result=handler._ioperation.mul(5, 2);
```

i have copied these from a site which is how to work with Ninject,to me it looks very odd,in my controller if you see i am using "new" key word and instantiate which as far as i know we should not do that otherwise whats the point of DI?can anyone explain me?

Comment: you shouldn't have any container code in your controller.  callling kernel.Get in a controller is a code smell.  replace your ControllerFactory with a custom one that will resolve the dependencies for you.

Comment: @Fran im pretty confused can you please write here how i should make it?

Comment: @Fran you mean i should use it in NinjectWebCommon?

Comment: There is a nuget package Ninject.MVCx where x is the version of MVC you are integrating with.  That should hold a custom controller factory that you can replace.

Comment: @Fran you mean the ninjectcimmonweb which added to app_start after installing from nuget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead on initializing in your controller, you should use the Application_Start() method in Global.asax file to register the bindings as then we'll not have to do the same for every controller. Refer this [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-ninject-framework-with-mvc/) for the complete implementation.

Comment: Then i dont need to instantiate anything in controller?

Comment: No, once you call it in the application_start method, the Ninject extension takes care of injecting the dependencies to the controllers and filters.

Comment: let me give it a try then i come back here :)

Comment: i think thats a really complicated way of using Ninject

Comment: how should i pass a class using this approach,imagine i have a class Students,i have a method and interface for it,should i pass the concrete class ?where i should instantiate the Student class?